# Cannot get to GUI

Tags: 23.04

I installed pytorch in the morning and then my laptop started working weird so when I restarted I got into the screen attached. I uninstalled pytorch, but I still have the same issue. Ctrl-Alt-F(1-6) does not work, all packages are up to date, firmware updates are also done, I tried to switch Dynamic to Discrete as suggested in BIOS, but there is no such setting.I also reinstalled lightdm, but it didn't work. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Final opening screen:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The next to last line suggests it is a gpu driver issue. Pytorch interacts and can modify the gpu driver/settings, I would suggest reinstalling the gpu drivers.  If it is a nvida based card, are you using the open source or proprietary driver?

If reinstalling the driver does not work, try changing the driver to/from open source.

You do have a number of other errors releting to firmware/drivers for devices, but I do not believe they would stop the gui from loading.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My laptop uses Intel iRIS xe graphics. So I dont know how can I reinstall the drivers.

Comment: I believe the Intel iRIS drivers are part of the xserver-xorg-video-intel package.